# Proof of the Law of Large Numbers

Tags: probability, combinatorics, law-of-large-numbers

I am studying and solving through the problems from the excellent monograph by Feller - `Introduction to probability theory and applications`. I am having some trouble understanding the derivation of the chapter VI.4 - the law of large numbers.

On page [159](https://archive.org/details/AnIntroductionToProbabilityTheoryAndItsApplicationsVolume1/page/n159/mode/2up), the author derives an expression for an upper bound for the ratio of two successive binomial terms $b(k;n,p)/b(k-1;n,p)$. For $k \ge (r+1)$:

\begin{align*}
    \frac{(n+1)p - pk}{kq} &\le \frac{(n-r)p}{(r+1)q}\\
    \frac{b(k;n,p)}{b(k-1;n,p)}&\le \frac{(n-r)p}{(r+1)q}
\end{align*}

Set herein, $k=r+1, \ldots, r+\nu$ and multiply the $\nu$ inequalities to obtain:
\begin{align*}
    \frac{b(r+1;n,p)}{b(r;n,p)} &\le \frac{(n-r)p}{(r+1)q}\\
    \frac{b(r+2;n,p)}{b(r+1;n,p)} &\le \frac{(n-r)p}{(r+1)q}\\
    \implies\frac{b(r+2;n,p)}{b(r+1;n,p)}\cdot \frac{b(r+1;n,p)}{b(r;n,p)} &\le \left(\frac{(n-r)p}{(r+1)q}\right)^2\\
    \implies\frac{b(r+2;n,p)}{b(r;n,p)}&\le \left(\frac{(n-r)p}{(r+1)q}\right)^2\\
    \implies\frac{b(r+\nu;n,p)}{b(r;n,p)}&\le \left(\frac{(n-r)p}{(r+1)q}\right)^\nu
\end{align*}

If we let this ratio, be less than unity $1$, that is :
\begin{align*}
    \frac{(n-r)p}{(r+1)q}& < 1\\
    \implies (n-r)p &< (r+1)q\\
    \implies np - rp &< (r+1)(1-p)\\
    \implies np - rp &< (r+1) - (r+1)p\\
    \implies np - rp &< (r+1) - rp - p\\
    \implies np &< (r+1) - p\\
    \implies (n+1)p &< (r+1)\\
    \implies (r+1) &> np + p
\end{align*}

> **Question.**
> How do I conclude that $r \ge np$?

For $r \ge np$, the fraction in the braces is less than unity, and the summation over $\nu$ leads to a finite geometric series with the ratio $(n-r)p/(r+1)q$. We conclude that for $r \ge np$, it must be bounded above by the infinite series:
\begin{align*}
    \frac{\sum_{\nu=0}^{n-r}b(r+\nu;n,p)}{b(r;n,p)} &\le 1+ \left(\frac{(n-r)p}{(r+1)q}\right) \\
    &+ \left(\frac{(n-r)p}{(r+1)q}\right)^2 + \ldots
\end{align*}

We can therefore write :

\begin{align*}
        \sum_{\nu=0}^{n-r}b(r+\nu;n,p) &\le b(r;n,p)\cdot \frac{1}{1-\frac{(n-r)p}{(r+1)q}}\\
        &=b(r;n,p)\cdot \frac{(r+1)q}{(r+1)q-(n-r)p} \tag{1}
\end{align*}

**Theorem. If $r \ge np$, the probability of atleast $r$ successes satisfies the above inequality.**

---

If $S_\nu$ is the number of successes in $n$ identical Bernoulli trials, $S_n/n$ is the average number of successes. Our *intuitive notion of probability* says, that $S_n/n \to p$, where $p$ is the probability of successes.

Consider, for example, the probability that $S_n/n$ exceeds $p + \epsilon$, where $\epsilon > 0$ is arbitrarily small but fixed. This probability is the same as $P(S_n > n(p + \epsilon)$ which equals the left side of (1). Then $(1)$ implies:

\begin{align*}
P\{S_n > n(p + \epsilon)\} < b(r;n,p) \frac{n(p+\epsilon)+q}{n{\epsilon} + q}
\end{align*}

> I am unable to derive the expression on the right hand side. How does that come about?

Comment: I'm not really following your question, since Feller's proof is broken down into two *cases*, one where $r\geq np$ and one where $r\leq np$. The bracketed expression he refers to is less than 1 in the former case. You seem to be working backwards, and if $(r+1)>np+p$, then $r>np+p-1>np$ since $p<1$.

Comment: @AlexR., (I) I don't quite follow, why $r \ge np$ leads to the ratio being less than $1$? (II) In the section on large numbers, f I plug in $r = n(p + \epsilon)$ into the expression for atleast $r$ successes, I don't get what Feller has mentioned.

Comment: You're saying "How do I conclude $r\geq  np$." I'm saying it's the other way around (or just reverse your steps). You assume $r\geq np$, and then $\frac{(n-r)p}{(r+1)q}\leq \frac{(n-np)p}{(r+1)q}=\frac{np}{r+1}\leq 1$

Comment: @AlexR. thanks I understand now. Could you also help me with the question (II)?